# .SDF Local Database Queries

Tags: database, date, sql-server-ce

I am working on stand alone windows form application with a local SQL Server CE database.

I am some how new to local database..

I faced problem with writing query to get records based on range of date for example to get records between `(1-july-2014)` and `(30-july-2014)`.

Can any one give me example or tell me the way?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM MyRecords
WHERE MyDateField >= @1 AND MyDateField <= @2
```

Use SqlCeParameters of DateTime type and assign the dates to these.

Comment: thanks for your replay i already tried this its not worked with me this was solved for me by using Convert :

SELECT        *
FROM            ExaminationFees
WHERE        (ExamDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '01/09/2014', 103)) AND (ExamDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '30/09/2014', 103))

Comment: It is much better to use parameterized SQL, as that will work across the world.

Answer (score 0):

this was solved by using Convert

SELECT        *
FROM            ExaminationFees
WHERE        (ExamDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '01/09/2014', 103)) AND (ExamDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '30/09/2014', 103))